# How to commit or rollback a change in database when using a custom context manager class with mysql connector

Tags: python, commit, mysql-connector, rollback, contextmanager

What is the best way to handle committing or rolling back a change in the database when using mysql connector through a custom context manager class. For example, say the custom class takes the form:

```
class DatabaseConnection:
    def __init__(self, host, user, password, database_name)
        self.host = host
        self.user = user
        self.passwd = password
        self.database_name = database_name
        self.connection = None

    def __enter__(self) -> Union[mysql.cursor.MySQLCursor, None]:
       try:
          if self.connection is None or not sef.connection.is_connected():
              self.connection = mysql.connect(
                  host = self.host, user=self.user, psswd=self.psswd, db=self.database_name
              )
          cursor = self.connection.cursor()
          return cursor
      except Exception:
          return None

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        if self.connection is not None: 
            self.connection.close()

    def commit(self):
        if self.connection is not None and self.connection.is_connected():
             try:
                 self.connection.commit()
                 return True
             except:
                 self.connection.rollback()

    def rollback(self):
        if self.connection is not None:
           self.connection.rollback()
```

And you then want to use that using the `with` statement so that you have the cursor. How would you manage commiting or rollback the changes, especially when errors are raised. For example:

```
test = True
database_connection = DatabaseConnection(....)
try:
    with database_connection() as cursor:
        # perform some operations

        if test:
            database_connection.rollback()
        else:
            database_connection.commit()
except Exception as e:
     database_connection.rollback()
```

Ignoring the bad practice with respect to error handling, would the commit and rolling back work as expected or would you have to organize it in a different way?

### EDIT

The above pattern seems to work as expected (if test, rollback, if not then commit and if exception then rollback). I'm not entirely sure why so any enlightenment on this regard would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: you are not entirely sure why what? why your code works?

Comment: Your try-except "eat" the exceptions instead of raising them again. The user has no clue that `commit` failed and instead did a rollback

Comment: Do the rollback in `__exit__` if the exc* arguments are not empty.

Comment: @UpAndAdam yes. I think the thing I wasn't sure about was the `if ... else ...` for commit and rollback.

Comment: @Homer512 In the final code I log that an exception was raised at the end and output it to a log.

Comment: And then you just continue as if nothing happened and as if the change had been committed to the database? Not sure what your app is doing but that sounds like a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @Homer512 The idea is that the `try...except` block would each be a part of a function that do different things. In one it could be writing to the db, in another querying, in another deleting. Each step should be isolated from each other where there is no knock on effect if one fails. If one fails all we want to do is notify the user that that step failed for x reason but for the overall program to simply continue through to the next step. I could probably make it a bit more robust but I don't want it to fall over if one step fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works because you have written it to handle all possibilities.  It is odd however that you don't make use of the object you create in the context manager.

Consider the possibilities:

1.Test succeeds:
`commit` is performed. (If commit throws an exception it will be caught and handled in your commit function)
2. Test fails:
`rollback` is performed.  (note however you have done this outside the context manager which is a little odd because the connection (for cursor at least) is closed )
3. An exception is thrown:
The exception is caught and a rollback is performed.

So all cases are handled. The one thing to note is that you probably want to log something to let a user know that you failed to commit and performed a rollback.
It is also notable that the syntax of:
`database_connection = DatabaseConnection(...)` doesn't me make sense if you want to use the context manager as you do on the next line. You should be able to condense the two lines to simply `with DatabaseConnection(...) as cursor:` and then replace usages of `database_connection` in the context manager with `cursor`. That's the point to using the context manager in the first place. Don't mix and match between two different objects that are the 'same'-ish connection to the database where one is context managed and the other isn't.  Thats bad coding and extremely unpythonic and could yield very unexpected results.

Which then raises @snakecharmerb's point that you should look at putting the rollback in the `__exit__` code. As it stands you are basically not using the context manager.

Comment: Thank you! I think the questions there point to where I am misunderstanding things. The Syntax of database_conection =  is becuase the object takes `host`, `user`, `password` and `databasename` which I want to reuse the object for different operations later on with the with statement. So I will pass this object elsewhere which will then open up their own context managers (I'm not sure whether this is the correct phrasing of this). i.e. multiple methods/objects will use DatabaseConnection ...

Comment: I would be using the `cursor` in the code covered by `#perform some operations`. Either qeuerying, inserting or deleting (in this case each in sequences). What you are suggesting is that instead of using `if test: database_connection.rollback()` I should be able to use `if test: cursor.rollback()`? Would that be better/clearer? (that's a little in what I am confused about)...

Comment: Then, if I put the `rollback` in the `__exit__` code, I wouldn't need to wrap it all in a `try...except` clause?

Comment: you may still need exception catching, but ill defer that to @snakecharmerb

Comment: Generally you would allow the exception to bubble up out of the context manager, so that the calling code knows something has gone wrong and can react appropriately.  For example a webapp might want to send a 500 response instead of a 200.  But ultimately it depends on your specific use-case.

Comment: yes. you should use cursor.rollback(), like i said you should eliminate the duplicate creation of the DatabaseConnection object.  Doing so twice and using one for some bits and the other for other bits a. defeats the purpose of the context manager and b. could lead to unexpected behavior because they are different objects.  I wouldn't expect things done to one to be visible in the other necessarily etc.

Comment: That the database_connection object takes arguments is not related to how you use it in a context manager or not.   I would advise you to either not reuse the object OR don't close the context so you can continue to use it within said context.

Comment: thanks @snakecharmerb  thats kind of what i thought ( that you would put it there for more business logic purposes) but wasnt positive. I had only provided my own enter and exit method like once and had forgotten all about them.

Comment: @snakecharmerb great, thank you! Just so that I understand properly, the `try...except` block as I'm using here is probably incorrect. Instead, the rollback under exception should be done in `__exit__`, while the `try...except` should catch and deal with any exceptions that bubble out of the context manager by the `__exit__` method returning `False`?

Comment: @UpAndAdam thank you! that clears things up with respect to the `if..else` for rollback or commit, thank you!

Comment: Personally I would close the connection in `__exit__` and rollback there too in the event of an exception.  However I would not catch the exception in the context manager, I would let the calling code handle it.  The idea is to separate responsibilities.  It's the responsibility of the context manager to make sure that the connection is left in a good state regardless of errors.  The responsibility of deciding what to do about any errors will usually lie somewhere else in the code.